# How to use the dialog jquery inside a php statement to display a message when saving records?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

SOLUTION

I hope someone finds this of use.

css to create a message box and icon.

```
.messagebox {
position:fixed;
background-color:#000000;
color:#ffffff;
margin-left:400px;
margin-top:100px;
border:3px solid #ffffff;
font-family:'Voltaire', sans-serif;
font-size:24px;
height:30px;
width:180px;
border-radius:15px;
z-index:1;
padding:7px 0px 7px 20px;
}

p.icon{
position:fixed;
left:28.2em;
top:375px;
width:20px; 
height:20px; 
background-color:#ffff00;
border-radius:1px;
margin-left:10%;
}
```

Firefox alignment fix :

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
p.icon {top:15.7em;}
}
```

First declare variable for displaying messages.

```
$message = $_GET['message'];
```

Example of query to redirect on save.

```
if($sql = mysql_db_query ($DBName, $Query, $Link)) {
$message = "Record Saved";
header("Location: edit.php?");
}
```

php inside HTML section :

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['message']) && !empty($message)): ?>
<div class="messagebox">
<?php echo $message ?><p class="icon">
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
</p>
```

jquery to close messagebox on click.

```
<script>
$('.messagebox').click(function(e) 
{e.stopPropagation();
})
 $(function(){
$(document).click(function(){  
$('.messagebox').hide();
});
});
</script>
```

[image: final]

---

I've configured the jquery script dialog. I want to display a confirmation message when a user saves a record. This is how I ran it when testing :

```
<div id="dialog">
<p class="messagebox">
Your changes have been saved
<?php print $message; ?></p>
</div>
```

The problem doing it that way is the page always display the message even when form data has not been saved so I need to excute this inside the php.

This is the query :

```
if($sql = mysql_db_query ($DBName, $Query, $Link)) {
$message = "Your changes have been saved";
$current = $_GET['page'];
header("Location: edit.php?");
}
```

I tried to get the dialog to run when changes are made like this :

```
if($sql = mysql_db_query ($DBName, $Query, $Link)) {
echo '
<div id="dialog">
'.$message = "Your changes have been saved".
header("Location: edit.php?");
```

But that gave me an error.

```
Your changes have been saved1
Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in edit.php on line 161
```

How do I get the dialog to only display when a user saves a record? Is there a way to add a close button to a css message box? It would be so much easier.

Comment: PHP only runs on the server, so when on the client (a user saves a record) in order to execute PHP code you must either make an XHR call or reload the page. It may help elaborate your problem if you show more code. When the user saves do you want to stay on the page? Or can you refresh the page to provide the confirmation message?

Comment: Thanks.

I already have a redirect in the same statement :

if($sql = mysql_db_query ($DBName, $Query, $Link)) {
$message = "Your changes have been saved";
$current = $_GET['page'];
header("Location: edit.php?page=".$current."&message=".urlencode($message)); 
}

Then in html :

<p class="error"><?php print $message; ?></p>

The problem is the message "Your changes have been saved" stays on screen which is why I thought about using a pop-up. Is there a way to refresh the page after the message has been displayed in the php statement above?

Comment: Are you wanting to concatenate those assignments? If not, change the dots at the end to semicolons. For example: `$message = "Your changes have been saved";`.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: I read your comment below, is this what you mean?

```
if($sql = mysql_db_query ($DBName, $Query, $Link)) {
    echo "'<p class="messagebox">' . $message . '<a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.style.display=\'none\';">Close</a></p>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I use the $message variable across all pages to pass messages and it's styled in a certain manner and I have media queries set to position it so I would prefer to avoid using alerts are they look a bit messy. Using the alert gave a php [] operator not supported for strings error which I managed to fix but I would prefer not to make too many changes if it interferes with other elements. Thought this would be easier!

Comment: Almost got it. I left the query as it. Then inside the html :

<?php echo '<p class="messagebox">'.$message.'</p>'?>

Now the message only displays when a change has been made only it stays on screen so I need I'm guessing javascript to link to the message so it closes on click.

Comment: Didn't work. I got the fatal error again. This pops up the message box when a record is saved but I need a way to close the box.

<?php if(isset($_GET['message']) && !empty($message)): ?>
<div class="messagebox">
<?php echo $message ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: Cracked it. Full solution below.